# Fix memory leak in third party library

Tags: python-3.x

Using python 3.6.8

We got a Out Of Memory error in our prod servers, when we investigated with tracemalloc the cause we found out that the main hoggers of memory were a line in simplejson decoder and a dict assignment, both called in a third party library. 
Our code looks like this:

```
with third_party.session(url, token)
   page = session.items()
   while True:
       for item in page:
           processed_item = process(item)
           yield processed_item
       try:
           page = page.next_page()
       except IndexError:
           break
```

The traceback on both the call to the method `parse_once` of simplesjson, and the assignment `self.attributes[key] = attr` which are the 2 top results in tracemalloc goes back to `page = page.next_page()`.

At an indefinite point of processing that is not even finished we got:
`/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400: size=52.3 MiB (+52.3 MiB), count=744785 (+744785), average=74 B`

I tried to `del` the object:

```
old_page = page
try
    page = page.next_page()
except IndexError:
    break
finally: 
    del old_page
```

But this approach didn't work.

Is it possible to control the memory leak that it is happening in a third party library?